# Null Reference to camera when loading new scene

Tags: unity, camera

I am getting the error:

> MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'Camera' has been
>   destroyed but you are still trying to access it. Your script should
>   either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.

The camera in my game contains a persistent object script, which prevents the camera from being destroyed when loading a new scene.

```
private void Awake()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
}
```

The scene is switched via a method in the GameManager:

```
public void loadScene(UnityEngine.Object arena)
{
    operation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(arena.name);
    state = GameState.LOADING; 
}
```

and finally the camera contains another script which adds a distortion effect:

```
void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture source, RenderTexture destination)
{
    distortCam.CopyFrom(mainCam); //Error occurs here
    distortCam.backgroundColor = Color.grey;
    // ...Some more code ...
}
```

The error occurs in this last method, but the camera still exists in the editor. `mainCam` is a Camera object that is assigned `onAwake` via `mainCam = GetComponent<Camera>();`

Also if I switch the `loadScene` method to:

```
public void loadScene(UnityEngine.Object arena)
{
    operation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(arena.name, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
    state = GameState.LOADING;
}
```

it works perfectly, but it is inconvenient to always have to loadScenes additive.

Why is the reference to the `mainCam` being lost? I have tried to check if it's null and reassigning it before using it, but so far I still have the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Try assigning the mainCam in Start (it runs after Awake) see if that fixes it.

Comment: @VadimTatarnikov I tried, but the problem persists.

Comment: It looks like you have two cameras involved here, `mainCam` and `distortCam`. Is it definitely `mainCam` that is null? I just made a test of `CopyFrom(null)` and got the message `Camera to copy from must not be null` instead of the exception.

Comment: Thanks you're actually right. It was not the mainCam that was being deleted but the distortCam which was created in the script and not being added to the persistentObjects